# Export function from C++ DLL

Tags: c++, dll, dllexport

`enter code here`  I was trying to export a class from a C++ dll. I defined DLL_TEST_EXPORTS as a macro and set the public and private functions and variables. My question is whether all the public variables and functions will be exported or I have to do something else to export them?

```
dll_test.h

#ifdef  DLL_TEST_EXPORTS 
/*Enabled as "export" while compiling the dll project*/
#define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)  
#else
/*Enabled as "import" in the Client side for using already created dll file*/
#define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllimport)  
#endif

class DLLEXPORT getWettedNodeForces{ 

private:
long int i, j, z, temp, k;
double Pmax, W, c, theta, R, c0, rho, P0, R2, tx, ty, tz, Angle, Vel, Vel1,   Vel2, Vel3, PT, PT1, Area, FT, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, tPmax, tV, test, yLow, yHigh, h;
double V1[3], V2[3], V3[3], V4[3], N[4], R3[3];


public:  
void getforce();    
int nodalForce.id; 
double nodalForce.x, nodalForce.y, nodalForce.z, wettedNodeForces;

};
```

Comment: It looks like they will be exported, have you encountered a problem with the visibility of the above public members? Can you tell us what issues you are encountering. It might also be valuable to know what linker parameters you are passing and what compiler you are using.

Comment: Thank you Jacob! I'm still considering to use explicit link or static link. I want to pass this DLL to another DLL. I would like the public parameters I defined in this DLL able to be used by the DLL import this DLL. One problem still confound me is if the public parameters I exported from this DLL will become private/public parameters in the DLL that import those parameters (Since I there will be a class in the accepting DLL, I think those exported parameters would become private if they are not declared as public). I'm using Visual Studio 2010.  Thanks!

Comment: And does the command used to export class or import class from DLL depend on the build tool I use? (I have to use Scons for some reason rather than the NMAKE provided by Visual Studio)